# Query Optimization / Fixing

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I had a similar problem the week before last with a query that was taking forever to run. In writing this query,  I tried to apply some of the things learnt from the other query, but yet it takes extremely long to execute.

When running the two individual parts of the query it takes 2 minutes each to complete which is acceptable, although quicker would be much better.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT
    x.entityCode    'Entity Code'
,   x.nnd_volume    'Latest Brand Volume'
,   maxDate         'Last Action Date'
,   x.Brand         'Brand Description'
,   (SELECT 
            ROUND(((SELECT (MAX(A.line_value * B.pack_volume)) 
                         FROM master_data.brand_master B 
                         WHERE A.brand_code = B.brand_code
                           AND A.brand_code = B.brand_code) 
                  / --THIS IS NOT A BUG, JUST TRYING TO CLEARLY INDICATE THE TWO SELECTS BEING DIVIDED AND CALCULATED
                   (SELECT C.case_volume 
                         FROM master_data.brand_master C 
                         WHERE A.brand_code = C.brand_code
                           AND A.brand_code = C.brand_code)),2) 'brand_volume' 
       FROM am_lines.brand_module A
       WHERE A.action_date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY))
         AND DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
         AND A.entity_code = x.entityCode
         AND A.brand_code = x.brandCode
       GROUP BY A.entity_code, A.brand
    ) 'Max Brand (28 Days)'
FROM
    (SELECT
        BBM.entity_code AS entityCode    
    ,   MAX(action_date) AS maxDate
    ,   brand AS Brand
    ,   brand_code AS brandCode
    ,   ROUND(((SELECT (BBM.line_value * B.pack_volume) 
        FROM master_data.brand_master B 
        WHERE BBM.brand_code = B.brand_code AND BBM.brand_code = B.brand_code) 
    / --THIS IS NOT A BUG, JUST TRYING TO CLEARLY INDICATE THE TWO SELECTS BEING DIVIDED AND CALCULATED
    (SELECT C.box_volume 
        FROM master_data.brand_master C 
        WHERE BBM.brand_code = C.brand_code AND BBM.brand_code = C.brand_code)),2) 'brand_volume' 
    FROM 
        am_lines.brand_module BBM
    WHERE 
        line_field_id IN (3154, 3655)
    AND action_date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))    
    GROUP BY
    --  action_date
        entity_code
    ,   brand_code) AS X
GROUP BY
    x.entityCode
,   x.brand;
```

SAMPLE DATA (The pack Volume and Box Volume is just a reference table which indicates the total units in a pack / box and is used for calculation and I have therefore not included it in the sample data):

```
    entity_code | action_date| brand    | line_value
    ------------+------------+----------+----------- 
    108792      |2016-12-07  |brand 001 | 25
    108793      |2016-12-08  |brand 002 | 36
    108795      |2016-12-06  |brand 003 | 10
    108796      |2016-12-05  |brand 004 | 55
    108795      |2016-12-13  |brand 001 |  5
    108792      |2016-12-14  |brand 003 |  2 
    108793      |2016-12-14  |brand 005 | 15 
    108796      |2016-12-16  |brand 006 | 25
```

CURRENT OUTCOMES THAT WORK:

- Each Select Query Runs in a few minutes (2 at most) and gives the
  desired result.
- The action_date and line_field_id are indexed.
- Adding an index to entity_code slow the table down for some unknown reason.

CURRENT ISSUES EXPERIENCED / DESIRED RESULT:

- The entire query run as one takes forever to run, in excess of 2
  hours.
- Each entity will sell / hold stock of a number of brands. I need to determine the MAXIMUM stock holding in a 28 day cycle as well as in a month (Max Holding 28 Days Column in Desired set).
- I will need to also show the latest week stock holding (Brand Holding Column In desired set).

DESIRED RESULT SET VIEW:

```
    entity_code | Last Date  | brand holding    | Max Holding (28 Days) |Brand
    ------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------+
    108792      |2016-12-27  |10                | 25                    |Brand 001
    108792      |2016-12-27  |36                | 36                    |Brand 002
    108792      |2016-12-27  |5                 | 10                    |Brand 003
    108792      |2016-12-27  |25                | 55                    |Brand 004
    108792      |2016-12-27  |4                 |  5                    |Brand 005
    108783      |2016-12-15  |80                | 80                    |Brand 001
    108783      |2016-12-15  |36                | 41                    |Brand 002
    108783      |2016-12-15  |12                | 12                    |Brand 003
    108783      |2016-12-15  |8                 | 11                    |Brand 004
    108783      |2016-12-15  |20                | 90                    |Brand 005
```

QUERY PLAN (store_code is the same as entity code, I just renamed it for the purpose of the post):
[image: QUERY PLAN (store_code is the same as entity code, I just renamed it for the purpose of the post):]

I have adjusted my index to be on action_date and line_field_id.

SHOW CREATE TABLE Image:
[image]

Comment: The brand module table has a few million lines. And an index is placed on the Entity Code.

Comment: can you provide us a query plan ?

Comment: Query Plan Added - Note the store_code is the same thing as the entity code. I only changed the column name for the purpose of the post.

Comment: `BBM.brand_code = B.brand_code AND BBM.brand_code = B.brand_code` -- sounds redundant??

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a few hints.  If they are not enough, let's start over.

- Many of the subqueries you have are not needed; you would be better of with `JOINs`.
- `CURDATE` has not time, so it does not need converting to `DATE`:  `DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY))` --> `(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 28 DAY)`
- Please use some kind of indentation to help differentiate the subqueries.
- What guarantees that `(SELECT ROUND...` returns only one row?  Perhaps the `GROUP BY` is redundant?
- Sometimes you use `brand`, sometimes `brand_code`; is this a 'bug'?
- Add the indexes below; I can't tell which ones would be best.

Indexes:

```
INDEX(action_date, entity_code, brand_code)
INDEX(line_field_id, action_date)
INDEX(entity_code, brand, action_date)
```

**Addenda**

- Do not use `VARCHAR` for values you need to compute with, such as `MAX(A.line_value * B.pack_volume)`.
- Do not blindly use `(255)` on `VARCHAR`, use 'reasonable' max lengths.
- Have a `PRIMARY KEY` on any InnoDB table.
- Mismatched types, such as `line_field_id IN (3154, 3655)` with `VARCHAR(900)` prevent reasonable optimizations and *may* yield 'wrong' results.

(I won't consider this Question further until at least the datatypes are 'fixed'.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try implement some of the changes you suggest. I just want to ask where you would suggest I use the JOINS rather than subqueries?

I noticed that having an index on my entity_code also slowed down my query quite a bit so I changed that (Not sure why that would happen). 

I therefore changed my index to line_field_id and action_date.

Comment: "changed my index" -- I was hoping you would add indexes, not change a single index.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With them, maybe I can guess at how to use `JOIN`.

Comment: Did add indexes :-)... But also had o remove the index from the entity code as it was drastically slowing down the table for some unknown reason. 

Using  SHOW CREATE TABLE. do I run that query on the table, or on the entire query?

Comment: One table.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE brand_module;` Ditto for other tables.

Comment: Hi there, 

I have added the SHOW CREATE TABLE